# Internet Speed Test

Tags: internet

I tested my speed with ookla. I also have a speed counter on my status bar (enabled using GravityBox). Both of them show different results. I tried another speed test site as well, an it shows another result. Can anyone explain whats going on and which one to trust?

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the difference of byte VS bit at play here - 1MB/s (byte) = 8Mbps (bit). The 2 speeds displayed match well.

As for different speed testing sites showing varying results: obviously they use different servers, bearing different route and latency. Speedtest (the one you're using) chooses the best based on ping, but not necessarily every site does.